# Is there a technical reason Mac OS X doesn't support SSL VPN?

Tags: macos, vpn, ssl

I noticed OS X doesn't support SSL VPN by default. Any technical reasons why this might be the case? (i.e. Any security concerns?)  What are the VPN protocols available for OS X?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Asking why Apple makes a decision is generally off topic here. If you are trying to solve a specific problem about using OS X as opposed to understanding Apple - please edit this and the hold will be reviewed.

Comment: Modified to address specific technical aspects and minimize degree of opinion. Thank you.